# ASP.NET configurando error 404

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hola amigos quiero tratar de cachar el error 404 de mi proyecto de asp.net , pero tengo problemas para redireccionar. Me tirá el siguiente error:

> System.Web.HttpException: 'Error al ejecutar la solicitud secundaria para /Errors/Error404.cshtml.'

No obstante ahí tengo mi vista, este mi codigo y una imagen de lo que estoy haciendo.

```
        protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // An error has occured on a .Net page.
        var serverError = Server.GetLastError() as HttpException;

        if (serverError != null)
        {
            if (serverError.GetHttpCode() == 404)
            {
                Server.ClearError();
                Server.Transfer("~/Errors/Error404.cshtml");
            }
        }

    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esto lo estoy haciendo sobre el archivo. `Global.asax`

Comment: Hola, indica por favor tu Web.config, mas en concreto la sección `<customErrors  />`.

Comment: no tengo un customErrors en mi web.config

Comment: ¿Estás siguiendo algún tutorial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu web.config

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error">
      <error redirect="~/Error/NotFound" statusCode="404" />
    </customErrors>
</system.web>
```

En tu controlador:

```
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
    public ViewResult Index()
    {
        return View("Error");
    }
    public ViewResult NotFound()
    {
        Response.StatusCode = 404;  //aqui podrías trabajarlo dinámicamente
        return View("NotFound");
    }
}
```

Y en tu vista:

```
@model System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorInfo
@{
    Layout = "_Layout.cshtml";
    ViewBag.Title = "Error";
}
<div class="list-header clearfix">
    <span>Error</span>
</div>
<div class="list-sfs-holder">
    <div class="alert alert-error">
        Ha ocurrido un error, contacta al administrador.
    </div>
    @if (Model != null && HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled)
    {
        <div>
            <p>
                <b>Exception:</b> @Model.Exception.Message<br />
                <b>Controller:</b> @Model.ControllerName<br />
                <b>Action:</b> @Model.ActionName
            </p>
            <div style="overflow:scroll">
                <pre>
                    @Model.Exception.StackTrace
                </pre>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Extraído y traducido de SOen https://stackoverflow.com/a/13905859/3613462

Comment: dejo el Application_Error dentro del  Global.asax ?

Comment: bro, esta industria avanza a punta de prueba, error y aprendizaje constante, intenta :D